# ¿Cómo leer datos de este JSON?

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, json

Tengo actualmente un select dependiente, al cambiar la selección, cambia el precio.

El Javascript para logralo es el siguienet:

```
<script>

  var service_id = {
    "0": [""],
    "1": ["45.00"],
    "2": ["00.00"],
    "3": ["25.00"]
  }

  function changePrice()

  {
    var combo = document.getElementById('service_id');
    var option = combo.value;
    
    document.getElementById('price').value = service_id[option][0];
    
  }
</script>
```

Ahora necesito generar el contenido de `var service_id` dinámicamente, se me ocurrió hacer un llamado `ajax` y returnar un `JSON`, lo obtengo pero no sé como leer los datos del `JSON` en la función:

```
function changePrice()

  {
    var combo = document.getElementById('service_id');
    var option = combo.value;
    
    document.getElementById('price').value = service_id[option][0];
    
  }
```

Mi llamado Ajax:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ route('options') }}",
      data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
      success: function(data) {
        datos = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(datos); 
      },
      error: function (error) { 
        console.log(error); 
      }
                               
    });  
    
  });                                  
</script>
```

Mi controlador:

```
public function options()
{
    $services = Service::all();

    if (!$services->isEmpty()) {

        foreach ($services as $service) {
            $elements[] = array($service->price);  
        }

        return $options = json_encode($elements);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar variables globales para esto por ejemplo

```
let datos = '';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ route('options') }}",
        data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
        success: function (data) {
            datos = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(datos);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

y para leer el valor del JSON puedes usar la variable global

```
function changePrice() {
    var combo = document.getElementById('service_id');
    var option = combo.value;

    document.getElementById('price').value = datos[option];
}
```

Es la opción mas sencilla pero de malas practicas, la que yo recomiendo es usar `get/set` de Javascript

Declaras tu variable global para meter y obtener los datos

```
const Datos = {
    get JSONDatos() {
        return this.__JSONDatos__;
    },
    set JSONDatos(value) {
        this.__JSONDatos__ = value;
    }
}
```

Luego para asignarle un valor a la variable Datos solo debes usar:

```
Datos.JSONDatos = Valores
```

Y para leer los datos guardados solo debes usar:

```
datos = Datos.JSONDatos
```

Con esto asignas y usas los valores guardados en todo tu codigo sin necesidad de utilizar variables globales, la puedes utilizar justo como lo harías con una variable global pero esto hace que tu codigo sea mas legible y con mejores practicas.

Comment: Gracias, por ambas opciones y la acotación de la mala y buena práctica. Voy a intentar y te aviso.

Comment: Pude resolverlo gracias a tu ayuda.